# How to find $ \frac{d}{dt} \left [\int_t^\infty xf(x)\,dx \right ]$ when $f$ is a probability density function?

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics

How can I solve this? I need intermediate equations. Maybe the answer is $-tf(x)$.

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left [\int_t^\infty xf(x)\,dx \right ] $$

$f(x)$ is probability density function.

That is to say, $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} F(x) = 1$

source: http://www.actuaries.jp/lib/collection/books/H22/H22A.pdf p.40

**Trying intermediate equations below:**

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \left [\int_t^\infty xf(x)\,dx \right ] = \frac{d}{dt} \left [\left [xF(x) \right ]_t^\infty - \int_t^\infty F(x)\,dx  \right ]??
$$

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \int_t^a f(x)\,dx = -\frac{d}{dt} \int_a^t f(x)\,dx = -\frac{d}{dt} (F(t)-F(a))=F'(t)=f(t)$$

Comment: Do you mean $\displaystyle \dfrac{d}{dt} \left [\int_t^\infty xf(x)~dx \right ]$?  Perhaps $-tf(t).$ Or do you mean $\displaystyle \dfrac{d}{dt} \left [\dfrac{\int_t^\infty xf(x)~dx}{1-F(t)} \right ]$?

Comment: Thanks, I modified the post. I can't solve only this part of equation.

Comment: Use the fundamental theorem of calculus

Comment: I'm trying now...

Comment: Consider a primitive $G$ of $x \mapsto xf(x)$, then $\int_t^\infty xf(x)dx=G(\infty)-G(t)$ is easy to derivate.

Comment: I can't get it. Could you help me?;( $\int xf(x)~dx = xF(x) - \int F(x)~dx !?$

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Read and added. Please note that I'm studying for a qualifying examination, so please give me a complete solution...

Comment: If you are studying for an exam, giving you the full solution is not the thing to do. Self-study questions are intended to bring the person asking the question to manage to solve the problem on one's own.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved...

$\displaystyle \dfrac{d}{dt} \left [\int_t^\infty xf(x)~dx \right ]$
$= \displaystyle \dfrac{d}{dt} \left [G(\infty)-G(t) \right ]$
$= \displaystyle \dfrac{d}{dt} \left [G(\infty) \right ] - \dfrac{d}{dt} \left [G(t) \right ]$
$= \displaystyle 0-tf(t)$

Thank you all!!!

Comment: What is $G(t)$ function? Why the derivative of $G(\infty)$ is 0?

Answer (score 15):

By definition, the derivative (*if it exists*) is the limit of the difference quotient

$$\frac{1}{h}\left(\int_{t+h}^\infty x f(x) dx - \int_t^\infty x f(x) dx\right) = -\frac{1}{h}\int_t^{t+h} x f(x) dx$$

as $h\to 0$.

*Assuming* $f$ is continuous within an interval $[t, t+h)$ for sufficiently small $h\gt 0$, $x f$ will also be continuous throughout this interval.  Then the [Mean Value Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#First_mean_value_theorem_for_integration) asserts there is some $h^{*}$ between $0$ and $h$ for which

$$-(t+h^{*})f(t+h^{*}) = -\frac{1}{h}\int_t^{t+h} x f(x) dx.$$

As $h\to 0$, necessarily $h^{*}\to 0$, and the continuity of $f$ near $t$ then implies the left hand side has a limit equal to $-t f(t)$.

(It is nice to see that this analysis requires no reasoning about the existence of the original *improper* integral $\int_t^\infty x f(x) dx$.)

**However,** even when a distribution has a density $f$, *that density does not have to be continuous.*  At points of discontinuity, the difference quotient will have different left and right limits: **the derivative does not exist there.**

---

This is not a matter that can be dismissed as being some arcane mathematical "pathology" that practitioners can ignore.  The PDFs of many common and useful distributions have points of discontinuity.  For example, the Uniform$(a,b)$ distribution has discontinuous PDF at $a$ and $b$; a Gamma$(a,b)$ distribution has a discontinuous PDF at $0$ when $a\le  1$ (which includes the ubiquitous Exponential distribution and some of the $\chi^2$ distributions); and so on.  Therefore, *it is important not to assert, without careful qualifications, that the answer is merely $-t f(t)$: that would be a mistake.*

Comment: A very small addendum: There are cases where the integral is differentiable even when $f(x)$ is not continuous. Let $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $f(x)=1$ for $0<x<1$ and $f(x)=0$ for $x\geq 2$. Then near 0, $F(x)=x^2/2$ for $x\geq 0$ and 0 for $x<0$, which is perfectly differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @Alex Near $0^{+}$, $F(x)=x$, not $x^2/2$.  Consider the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I define $F(x) := \int_{-\infty}^x tf(t)dt$.

Comment: @Alex Your integrand $tf(t)$ is continuous near zero, so I fail to see what kind of example you are presenting or what it shows.

Comment: Great derivation (+1) - it might be worth nothing that this result is a case of [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: @Ben Thank you.  It's really just the fundamental theorem of calculus, but I formulated it with special care in response to the OP's own answer, which glossed over the subtleties and therefore is only sometimes correct.